# How to get an authorization code from the Cognito API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I am implementing an OIDC compliant identity solution and want to use Cognito as an identity store that my server interacts with.

Given a set of user credentials I want to use Cognito to generate an authorization code that I can relay back to the user's browser. However, I cannot find such a method in the Cognito API. I found [AdminInitiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html), but this method eventually returns to me a set of tokens, instead of an authorization code. I can't seem to be able to customise this behaviour and I'm unable to find another method in the API that returns an auth code instead.

I was considering to use the [Authorize endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html), but this seems like a bad fit, because it uses redirects and is intended to be called from a browser.

Does there exist a method in the Cognito API to achieve what I intend? If not then is there an alternative approach I could use?